# Extended PDA vs TM

Tags: automata, turing-machines

We studied in class that PDA is less powerful than TM.

My question is:

> Extended PDA : for every $\alpha,\beta \in \Gamma \cup \{\epsilon\}$, $\sigma \in \Sigma \cup \{\epsilon\}$, $q,r \in Q$, $w \in \Sigma^*$,$\gamma \in \Gamma^*$:
>
> if $(q,b) \in \Delta(r,\sigma,\alpha,\mathrm{up})$ than $(r,\sigma w, \alpha \gamma) \to (q,w,\beta \gamma)$
> and if $(q,b) \in \Delta(r,\sigma,\alpha,\mathrm{down})$ than $(r,\sigma w, \gamma \alpha ) \to (q,w,\gamma \beta)$ is equivalent to TM?

I think that it's correct, because extended PDA can implement a queue automaton which is equivalent to TM.

Comment: What is what in the tuples?

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė I didn't understand your question.

Comment: You'll have to explain what all those Greek letters mean; otherwise your question doesn't make any sense. (There's no real standard for which letters to use for what about these things, so you cannot expect us to know what which letter is used to mean in the particular textbook you use).

Comment: @automata123 : Don't leave the curly braces outside of the MathJax environment; just put backslashes on them to make them visible.  Thus: $\{\varepsilon\}$ rather than {$\varepsilon$} ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I agree with @HenningMakholm that you should explain what those Greek symbols stand for because different books use different conventions. And also what do up and down operations mean in the transition function?

Comment: I see some edits, but there are still no explanations of what those letters are supposed to mean. In order to get a good chance of a useful answer, you'll need to explain **in words** how your extended automata work, not just leave it to the reader to attempt to decipher a naked formalism with no explanations to help.